# XSLT template with default namespace prefix not matching

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to write a XSLT filter transform that inserts a child element. Here is the input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://example.org">
    <child info="first"/>
    <child info="second"/>
</root>
```

My XSLT transform looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns="http://example.org" 
    xpath-default-namespace="http://example.org">

    <!-- insert new child element at front -->
    <xsl:template match="child[1]">
        <child info="very first"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- standard copy template -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The copy template works fine, but the template that is supposed to do a special action does not. I already tried several proposals of other posts, but with no avail. I can run XSLT 2.0, but changing the input files by using a prefix is not an option.

Comment: The above XSLT does insert the "very first" child node. See http://xsltransform.net/bnnZVL. Are you definitely sure you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor?

Comment: "*The copy template works fine, but the template that is supposed to do a special action does not.*" In what way it does not work (or work fine)? Post your expected result.

Comment: Add `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>` to output the XSLT version you are using. Your results are consistent with what an XSLT 1.0 processor should give.

Comment: You are right: I was using a XSLT 1.0 processor. I am working with Eclipse and was sure there would be an error message if the processor would not be capable of processing XSLT 2.0. With Saxon9 it works.